# Why do I get the error 'Type does not conform to protocol' when using a struct that conforms to the protocol?

Tags: swift

I've got a protocol called `DTO`.

```
public protocol DTO {
    static func GetDefaultInstance() -> DTO
}
```

I've got a struct that conforms to `DTO` called `Exercise`.

```
public struct Exercise: Codable, Identifiable, DTO {
    public var id: String { return ExerciseId }
    public var ExerciseId: String
    public var ExerciseName: String
    
    public static func GetDefaultInstance() -> Exercise { //error here
        return Exercise(ExerciseId: "", ExerciseName: "")
    }
}
```

Since `Exercise` conforms to `DTO` why can't I return `Exercise`? It is a `DTO`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the signature in the protocol and the declaration don't actually match, because while `Exercise` conforms to `DTO`, it is not exactly `DTO`.

If you change the protocol definition to return `Self`, then the protocol will expect that the function returns the type that is implementing the protocol, and that method signature you have will work.

```
public protocol DTO {
    static func GetDefaultInstance() -> Self
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that in your protocol definition you define, you are expecting to return something **which conforms to the `DTO`** **type**, but instead your are trying to return a concrete type, the `Exercise`. To fix this you just need to return a DTO type in your `GetDefaultInstance` function:

```
public static func GetDefaultInstance() -> DTO {
    return Exercise(ExerciseId: "", ExerciseName: "")
}
```